# template function name in terms of template argument

Tags: c++, templates, overloading

I've been looking for examples that relate to what my question is about and I still cannot find a solution. The closest thing I've found is

[Template function as a template argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697180/template-function-as-a-template-argument)

I will try to post a working example in case it is needed but so far part of my code involves the
following:

```
template<class InterfaceType, class T> 
inline void write_info(InterfaceType& interface, T& t) {
    InterfaceType::write_info(interface, t);
}

template<class InterfaceType, class T> 
inline void write_data(InterfaceType& interface, T& t) {
    InterfaceType::write_data(interface, t);
}

template<class InterfaceType, class T> 
inline void write_definition(InterfaceType& interface, T& t) {
    InterfaceType::write_definition(interface, t);
}
```

Notice that the templates `write_info` depend on an interface type which has a method called `write_info` (A static method). The reason this is done is because the `write_info` function can 
be specialized later on for an specific datatype without having to redefine anything on the `InterfaceType`.

The simple question is: Can we reduce the above code with a template that names the function as a function parameter? Keep in mind that I really want this to be possible so that I can avoid defining all those 3 function for a specialized datatype, i.e.

Suppose that `foo` is a structure with two attributes `int a` and `double b`. Then I can specialize the above functions like this:

```
template<class InterfaceType> 
inline void write_info(InterfaceType& interface, foo& t) {
    InterfaceType::write_info(interface, t.a);
    InterfaceType::write_info(interface, t.b);
}

template<class InterfaceType> 
inline void write_data(InterfaceType& interface, foo& t) {
    InterfaceType::write_data(interface, t.a);
    InterfaceType::write_data(interface, t.b);
}

template<class InterfaceType> 
inline void write_definition(InterfaceType& interface, foo& t) {
    InterfaceType::write_definition(interface, t.a);
    InterfaceType::write_definition(interface, t.b);
}
```

As you can see I'm writing the same code over and over again. Here I'm assuming that the InterfaceType already has define `write_info`, `write_data` and `write_definition` for `int` and `double`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turn the logic around:  rather than writing specialized `write_thing` overloads for each type, write a single `apply` function that applies an arbitrary function to an object of each type, then have a single overload of each `write_thing` that simply delegates to the `apply`:

```
// Define a catch-all apply that handles "everything else"
template <typename Interface, typename Function, typename Object>
void apply(Interface& i, Function f, Object& x) {
    f(i, x);
}

// Define overloads for "apply" that handle special cases
template <typename Interface, typename Function>
void apply(Interface& i, Function f, foo& x) {
    f(i, x.a);
    f(i, x.b);
}

// Define polymorphic adapters for your write_[thing] functions:
struct write_info_impl {
    template <typename Interface, typename Object>
    void operator()(Interface& i, Object& x) const {
        Interface::write_info(i, x);
    }
};

// Then implement your write_[thing] functions in terms of the above:
template <typename Interface, typename Object>
void write_info(Interface& interface, Object& x) {
    apply(i, write_info_impl(), x);
}
```

Comment: I like this logic but it seems that the compiler doesn't know which `&Interface::write_info` to use. Obviously we want to use the one that takes care of the type we are using in `apply`. Is there a way to tell it explicitly that we are using `&Interface::write_info<Object>`? Otherwise it g++ tells `<unresolved overloaded function type>` in the place of the function.

Comment: @jmlopez:  Ah, true.  You can use a generic functor to encapsulate the overload set.  See the update.  It's a bit more code, but if the `write_[thing]` functions are all as similar as they appear, you can trivially generate them using a macro.

Comment: Nice answer. 1 hour without upvotes? The Lounge must be with recess

Comment: Sorry it took me a while to check this new code. Now it compiles and it works up to a certain point. It works for the basic types: `int` and `double`. But for the special case `foo`, and doesn't use the right apply. Any ideas why the compiler would ignore the overload `apply` for the special case when `Object` is `foo`?

Comment: Never mind!! :) Seems that I don't have a good understanding of `::`. I was writing `::apply` instead of just `apply`. I changed it to the regular and it works. Will this give me some trouble if I put all the code under a namespace?

Comment: Right, the call must be unqualified (i.e., without any `::`'s) in order for argument-dependent lookup to be used based on the template argument types.  Each of the `apply` functions needs to be in either (a) the namespace in which `Interface` is defined or (b) the namespace in which `Object` is defined (or an enclosing namespace of one of those, though generally it's best to place the overloads in the same namespace).

Comment: Thanks James. This really simplifies the code. I hope that the namespaces doesn't case me trouble later on. I will require all the overloads of the objects to be defined in the same namespace.