# variadic templates with template function names for c++11

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates, variadic-functions

following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39316735/c-decorator-pattern-static-polymorphism-with-templates-and-registering-callba) question , I am trying to avoid copy-pasting some code related to calling all of the same-named methods of the mixins of the class `BaseSensor`.

in sensor.hpp

```
struct EdgeSensor //a mixin
{
    void update(){}
    void printStats() {}
};

struct TrendSensor //another mixin
{
    void update(){}
    void printStats() {}
};

template<typename ... SensorType>
class BaseSensor : public SensorType ... //to my BaseSensor class
{
    void update() /*{ what goes in here??? }*/
    void printStats() /*{ what goes in here??? }*/
};
```

in sensor.t.hpp

```
template<typename ... SensorType>
void BaseSensor<SensorType...>::update()
{
    int arr[] = { (SensorType::update(), 0)..., 0 };
    (void)arr;
}

template<typename ... SensorType>
void BaseSensor<SensorType...>::printStats()
{
    int arr[] = { (SensorType::printStats(), 0)..., 0 };
    (void)arr;
}
```

in main.cpp

```
int main(int , const char **) 
{
    {
        BaseSensor<EdgeSensor,TrendSensor> ets;
        ets.update();
        ets.printStats();
    }
    {
        BaseSensor<EdgeSensor> ets;
        ets.update();
        ets.printStats();
    }
}
```

The above code executes the `update()` of all the mixins in turn, before going on to execute all the `printStats()` from all the mixins as well.

I wonder if it is somehow possible to avoid duplicating the implementation of `BaseSensor::update()` and `BaseSensor::printStats()` and create a generic (template) function that accepts the name of the target function to execute across all the mixins:

For example, I could create a method `runAll()`

```
template<typename ... SensorType>
class BaseSensor : public SensorType ... //to my BaseSensor class
{
    void update() /*{ what goes in here??? }*/
    void printStats() /*{ what goes in here??? }*/

    template<typename FnName>
    void runAll(FnName f)
    {
        int arr[] = { (SensorType::f(), 0)..., 0 };
        (void)arr;
    }
};
```

How would I call it then from `BaseSensor::update()` and `BaseSensor::printStats()`. I have attempted to use

```
void update() { runAll<update>(); }
void printStats() { runAll<printStats>(); }
```

but this does not work (did not expect it to). The problem with passing function name as a function argument (which I see is many other questions such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12606408/template-function-name-in-terms-of-template-argument) is that I do not know how to point to various `::update()` functions from `BaseSensor::update()`. for example

```
void update() { runAll<update>( update() ); }
```

is also not correct.

Is it possible to avoid copying in this case? Can this be done in a one-liner so as to avoid alot of copying using c++11 (i.e. without using generic lambdas as is done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39558976/variadic-templates-with-template-function-names/39559160#39559160))? How would the template parameters look like if I where to move a working `runAll()` into file "sensor.t.hpp" ?

Thank you.

Comment: Link-only answers are bad, same apply for questions. Add relevant part to be self sufficient.

Comment: @Jarod42 ok fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the functions to be called are two, you can use a dedicated structure and rely on overloading to solve it.
It follows a minimal, working example:

```
#include<iostream>

struct Executor {
    template<typename T>
    static void execute(int, T &t) {
        t.update();
    }

    template<typename T>
    static void execute(char, T &t) {
        t.printStats();
    }
};

struct EdgeSensor
{
    void update() { std::cout << "EdgeSensor::update" << std::endl; }
    void printStats() { std::cout << "EdgeSensor::printStats" << std::endl; }
};

struct TrendSensor
{
    void update() { std::cout << "TrendSensor::update" << std::endl; }
    void printStats() { std::cout << "TrendSensor::printStats" << std::endl; }
};

template<typename ... SensorType>
class BaseSensor : public SensorType ...
{
    template<typename T>
    void execute() {
        int arr[] = { (Executor::execute(T{}, static_cast<SensorType&>(*this)), 0)..., 0 };
        (void)arr;
    }

public:
    void update() {
        execute<int>();
    }

    void printStats() {
        execute<char>();
    }
};

int main() {
    BaseSensor<EdgeSensor,TrendSensor> ets;
    ets.update();
    ets.printStats();
}
```

In case you have more than two functions to be called, I guess the `choice` trick applies well here.

Comment: hm still there are parts (in the struct) that need to be replicated for every other similar function. It appears the only Truly generic way are the generic lambdas...

Comment: I would use some enum/tag for dispatching instead of uninformative `char`/`int`

Comment: @Jarod42 I would do that too. From my point of view, the `int`/`char` trick is more concise for an example, that's all.

Answer (score 1):

You can still write the (simplified version of) generic lambda manually:

```
void update() {
    execute([](auto &t) { t.update(); });
}
```

becomes so

```
void update() {
    struct {
        template <typename T>
        void operator () (T& t) const { t.update(); }
    } updater;
    execute(updater);
}
```

Comment: hi there, thank you for the information . This still seems "long" for copy-pasting it. Ideally, I could get the struct "out" somehow and provide a "variable" name for the `t.update()` function call ? thank you

Comment: This is quite tricky when you are to introduce the _second_ function indeed.