# Specify a template argument which could bind to a function template

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

I am trying to write a higher-order function which would wrap around the standard library functions taking input and output iterators. Here's a failed attempt:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

template <template <typename, typename> class Func, typename InpIt, typename UnaryFunction>
decltype(Func<InpIt, UnaryFunction>(declval<InpIt>(), declval<InpIt>(), declval<UnaryFunction>())) Apply(InpIt first, InpIt last, UnaryFunction f)
{
  return Func<InpIt, UnaryFunction>(first, last, f);
}

int main()
{
  vector<int> a(5);
  Apply<for_each>(a.begin(),
                  a.end(),
                  [](int i)
                  {
    cout << i << endl;
  });
  return 0;
}
```

Clang 3.5 fails with

```
high.cpp:16:3: error: no matching function for call to 'Apply'
  Apply<for_each>(a.begin(),
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
high.cpp:8:100: note: candidate template ignored: invalid explicitly-specified argument for template parameter 'Func'
decltype(Func<InpIt, UnaryFunction>(declval<InpIt>(), declval<InpIt>(), declval<UnaryFunction>())) Apply(InpIt first, InpIt last, UnaryFunction f)
```

What is the right way to express this? Also, what I would ideally want is to be able to simply say something like

```
template <MagicIncantation Func, typename Range, typename ... Args>
MoreMagic Apply(Range&& rng, Args&& ... args)
{
  using std::begin; using std::end;
  Func(begin(rng), end(rng), args...);
}
```

allowing one to avoid specifying iterators when you want to iterate over the full range.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Template function as a template argument](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697180/template-function-as-a-template-argument)

Answer (score 2):

You'll find useful information in [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697180/template-function-as-a-template-argument), but what comes out of it is that you can't pass function templates as template (template) parameters, so passing `std::for_each` that way is not possible.

Comment: Upvote for the link. Leaving this unaccepted to see if someone would suggest a good alternative.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a wrapper class as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697180/template-function-as-a-template-argument#answer-4697356):

```
template <template <typename, typename> class Func, typename InpIt, typename UnaryFunction>
UnaryFunction Apply(InpIt first, InpIt last, UnaryFunction f)
{
    return Func<InpIt, UnaryFunction>::f(first, last, f);
}

template<typename T, typename T2>
struct for_each_wrapper
{
    static T2 f(T ta, T tb, T2 t2)
    {
        return std::for_each(ta, tb, t2);
    }
};

int main()
{
    vector<int> a(5);
    Apply<for_each_wrapper>(
        a.begin(),
        a.end(),
        [](int i)
    {
        std::cout << i << endl;
    });
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This doesn't help me with the goal specified in the latter half of my problem though.

Comment: Having to write a wrapper for each function I want to support defeats the purpose of `Apply` as a higher-order function meant to wrap other functions. If it were possible to write an `Apply` taking a template template function argument, I would be able to say `Apply<for_each>`, `Apply<transform>` and so on.

Comment: @Pradhan But why? Just call `std::for_each` or `std::transform` directly.

Comment: To avoid specifying iterators when I want to loop over the full range. `boost::algorithm` would have a bunch of them available, but I wanted to see if it was possible to solve in this way. It isn't a big deal if you are dealing with named ranges, but it is a pain if you just want to use an unnamed temporary. I can't write `std::for_each(SomeRangeReturningFunc(...).begin(), <what here?>, unary_op)`.

Comment: @Pradhan So you basically want to call std `std::for_each` / `std::transform` without calling `a.begin()` and `a.end()`?