# Instantiate member function templates for multiple types

Tags: c++, templates, instantiation, c++03, explicit-instantiation

I have a several classes with templated member functions and a predefined list of types they will be used with ([Wandbox link](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Un6fdSHWpA2Q9ttX):

```
// main.cpp:
#include "class.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    A a;
    a.foo(5);
    a.foo(5.);
    B b;
    //b.bar(1,2,3,4); b.bar(1,2,3.,4);
    return 0;
}

// class.h
#pragma once

struct A {
    template<typename T> void foo(T x);
};
struct B {
    template<typename T> void bar(int p1, int p2, T x, int p3);
};


// class.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "class.h"

template<typename T> void A::foo(T x) {
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
}

// explicit, but very verbose
// template void A::foo(int);
// ...

template<typename T> void ignore(T fn) {/* Use fn? */}

template<class Class>
void instantiate(Class) {
    // List all types the function should be instantiated for here
    ignore(&Class::template foo<int>);
    ignore(&Class::template foo<double>);
}

// works, instantiates A::foo<int> and A::foo<double>
template void instantiate(A);
// How to pass B::foo and additional parameters?
// template void instantiate(B);
```

Typing out every combination of member function and type to be instantiated with works, but it has several drawbacks:

- it's tedious
- the whole function signature with every parameter has to typed out, and
- function signature changes have to be made in several places
- adding a single type to the list has to be made for every member function

My workaround as above works on most older compilers I've tested (C++03 compatibility would be a huge plus), but I'm not sure if a smart compiler would be allowed to remove the unused parameter and the function instantiations.

For regular functions, there are [workarounds](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4697356/73299), but as far as I understood, they don't work for member functions.

How can I change my `instantiate` function to also accept a member function and additional parameters?

Comment: Instead of `ignore(...)` you can just do `static_cast<void>(...)`.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin Not with member function pointers, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/1307379/73299

Comment: I believe you need to do some form recursive template / template metaprogramming. Boost has some good assisting libraries for helping with this, for example in boost MPL / type tuples and perhaps boost variant for some higher level utilization. Unfortunately, it usually requires a good amount of work to make right and it is far from trivial, but in the end i believe you can get to the scaleable solution you are looking after.

Answer (score 1):

After much trying and erroring I found something that works even with optimizations enabled ([Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/UmIAUFbJfdwEHOHs)):

```
// main.cpp as above

// class.h
#pragma once

// Create instantiations for templated functions by keeping their addresses
// and therefore forcing the compiler to keep their object code
// attribute((unused)) silences the clang/gcc warning
template <typename T> void ignore(T t) {static __attribute__((used)) T x = t;}

struct A {
    template<typename T> void foo(T x);
    template<typename T> friend void instantiate(T); // let instantiate call the helper function in case it's private
    // helper function that instantiates all member functions
    template<typename T> void helper() { ignore(&A::foo<T>); }
};
struct B {
    template<typename T> void bar(int p1, int p2, T x, int p3);
    // same procedure as above
    template<typename T> friend void instantiate(T);
    template<typename T> void helper() { ignore(&B::bar<T>); }
};


// class.cpp
#include 
#include "class.h"

template void A::foo(T x) {
    std::cout  void B::bar(int, int, T, int) {}

template
void instantiate(Class) {
    // List all types the function should be instantiated for here
    ignore(&Class::template helper);
    ignore(&Class::template helper);
}

template void instantiate(A);
template void instantiate(B);
```

To avoid more complicated template magic, I added a single template function (`template<typename T> void helper()`) that gets instantiated by the `instantiate` function where all desired types for the functions to be instantiated with are listed.

Afterwards, `template void instantiate(A)` will instantiate all member functions listed in `A::helper`.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not valid, see [A function template, member function of a class template, variable template, or static data member of a class template shall be defined in every translation unit in which it is implicitly instantiated unless the corresponding specialization is explicitly instantiated in some translation unit; no diagnostic is required.](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp#11). Only `instantiate<A>` and `instantiate<B>` are explicitly instantiated. No `A::foo<T>` are explicitly instantiated :/ only implicitly.