# Function-typed member variable selecting from iterators

Tags: c++, templates, std-function

#### Goals

- A class with a function-typed member variable that can be used to choose a value from a range of values denoted by two iterators
- Should work in C++14, but if a (much) better solution is only possible in 17 or 20, I'd be interested nonetheless

#### Problem and Solution Sketch

Below is a sketch of the envisioned solution, with `???` denoting the choose-function's type, which I can't work out.

```cpp
template<typename E>
class Producer {
  ??? choose_from; // A function It × It → E
  ...
public:
  Producer(??? cf): choose_from{cf} {}

  E next() {
    // Get a bunch of values from internal state (omitted for brevity).
    // Could also be another container, e.g. std::set.
    std::vector<E> values = ...;

    return choose_from(values.begin(), values.end());
  }
}
```

Next up, a few example usage sketches of such a `Producer`. A solution that only supports a subset of those would still be fine.

- In combination with an existing function:

  ```cpp
  auto p = Producer<int>(std::max_element)`;
  ```
- In combination with a lambda function:

  ```cpp
  auto p = Producer<int>([](auto begin, auto end)) { ... });
  ```
- In combination with a custom free function:

  ```cpp
  template<typename E, typename It>
  E my_selector(It begin, It end) { ... }

  auto p = Producer<int>(my_selector);
  ```

#### Question

How do I get the code to work, i.e. what's the/a right type for member variable `choose_from`?

#### Attempt & Thoughts

- I've tried to use `std::function` to type `choose_from`, but since there is no abstract iterator type (AFAIK), I'm basically stuck at `std::function<E(IT?, IT?)>`.
- If the use of `std::vector` in `Producer::next()` were leaked, I could fix `choose_from`'s type to handle `std::vector<E>::iterator`s, but I'd much rather keep that internal detail hidden.

Comment: Maybe `template<typename E, typename CF> ...`? Otherwise `std::function` may be an option?

Comment: If your usage is `choose_from(values.begin(), values.end())` then `std::function<E(std::vector<E>::iterator, std::vector<E>::iterator)>`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::min_element` is a function template, there isn't much you can do with it by itself. Function templates are problematic - they can't be passed as a template argument, [nor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697180/template-function-as-a-template-argument) as function argument.

If you're OK with wrapping it in a generic lambda, then there's a generic solution possible:

```
template<class E, class F>
class Producer {
    F choose_from; // A function It - It → It

public:
    Producer(F const& cf) : choose_from{ cf } {}

    E next() {
        std::vector<E> values{ 5, 2, 3 };

        return *choose_from(values.begin(), values.end());
    }
};

template<typename E, typename F>
auto make_producer(F const& cf) {
    return Producer<E, F>(cf);
}

template<typename It>
It my_selector(It begin, It end) { return begin; }

int main() {
    auto p1 = make_producer<int>([](auto from, auto to) { return from; });
    cout << p1.next() << endl;
    auto p2 = make_producer<int>([](auto from, auto to) { return std::min_element(from, to); });
    cout << p2.next() << endl;
    auto p3 = make_producer<int>([](auto from, auto to) { return my_selector(from, to); });
    cout << p3.next() << endl;
}
```

Notes:

- There's also no partial CTAD, so even in C++17 you'd need a helper function (`make_producer()` above).
- `std::function` comes with run-time overhead (1..2 extra indirections). It should be used only when run-time polymorphism is unavoidable (e.g. dynamic callbacks) -- not the case here. Do not use.