# C++ template function pointer type deduction

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, lambda, type-deduction

I have the following code

```
using my_map_t = std::map<int, Object<double>>;
using my_map_iterator_t = my_map_t::iterator;


template <typename FWD, typename Func>
void inner(my_map_t& map, int key, FWD&& obj, Func emplacer) {
        emplacer(map, key, std::forward<FWD>(obj));
}
  

my_map_t map;

template <typename FWD>
void outer(my_map_t& map, int key, FWD&& obj)
{
        auto lambda = [](my_map_t& m, int k, FWD&& o) {
                m.emplace(k, std::forward<FWD>(o));
        };

        inner(map, key, std::forward<FWD>(obj), lambda);
}
```

which compiles painlessly. So this means that he deduce automatically the template argument of `inner` function.
However, if I introduce a function pointer I need to specify the function pointer template argument, otherwise the compiler complaints

```
using my_map_t = std::map<int, Object<double>>;
using my_map_iterator_t = my_map_t::iterator;


template <typename FWD, typename Func>
void inner(my_map_t& map, int key, FWD&& obj, Func emplacer) {
        emplacer(map, key, std::forward<FWD>(obj));
}

template <typename FWD, typename Func>
void(*fp)(my_map_t&, int, FWD&&, Func) = &inner;


my_map_t map;

template <typename FWD>
void outer(my_map_t& map, int key, FWD&& obj)
{
        auto lambda = [](my_map_t& m, int k, FWD&& o) {
                m.emplace(k, std::forward<FWD>(o));
        };

        (*fp<FWD, decltype(lambda)>)(map, key, std::forward<FWD>(obj), lambda);
}
```

Why in the case of function pointer the argument deduction is not working any more?
Did I make some mistake? Is there a way to achieve a better syntax?

## NOTE ADDED

I need to use function pointer because I have some function with the same signature of `inner`. Let us call them `inner1`, `inner2` and `inner3`. They are called by some outer function

```
void outer(...) {
     if(...) {

         inner1(...)
     } else if (...) {
     
         inner2(...)
     } else {

         inner3(...)
     }
     some_long_task(...)
}
```

Now in my case  the `outer` function is called cyclically. The checks in the `if`s can be time consuming and they are independent of the argument of `outer` function. I was thinking while the `some_long_task` is being executed, to set up a function pointer to the `right` function `inner1`, `inner2` or `inner3` exploiting some cpu parallelism, so that, the the new cycle begin, I do not have to waste time doing the if check.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Is it possible to achieve the same result without using a variable template (I discovered that they were introduced in c++14 and I must attain to C++11)?

Comment: why you require `fp` to be a function pointer? why not a lambda? since C++14 you can define `fp` as `[](my_map_t& map, int key, auto&& obj, auto func){ inner(map, key, std::forward<decltype(obj)>(obj), func); }`, or define a *functor* same as this lambda in C++11.

Comment: My point is thatI would have to define the  functor (since I use c++11)  inside a function. Is it possible?

Comment: no. similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66762246/function-typed-member-variable-selecting-from-iterators) and others these days, you want some functors to have a template interface but to be a single type. that's impossible, unless there is *virtual function template* in future C++.

Comment: Issue with your "function pointer" is that you cannot really capture extra data (you pass lambda currently). `std::function<void(my_map_t&, int)>` might be what you want instead of function pointer.

Answer (score 3):

```
template <typename FWD, typename Func>
void(*fp)(my_map_t&, int, FWD&&, Func) = &inner;
```

is not a normal function pointer.  It is what's called a [variable template](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variable_template).  When you have a variable template, in order to refer to a specific instantiation, you must specify the template parameters.  To demonstratre that, consider

```
template <typename T>
constexpr T pi = T(3.1415926535897932385L);
```

You can't just do `cout << pi` because we don't know which `pi` to use.  The same occurs with

```
(*fp<FWD, decltype(lambda)>)(map, key, std::forward<FWD>(obj), lambda);
```

Here `fp` needs the `<FWD, decltype(lambda)>` so the compiler can know which specific `fp` instance to refer to.  It has to do this even before it evaluates the function call because it needs to check the parameters against the function.

What we would need to not have to specify the parameter is a future like [CTAD](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variable_template) but would work for function pointer variable temapltes.

Comment: I understand, thanks so much. Btw, is there a way to avoid the use of variable template? I was thinking to use a templated class overloading `operator()` and then use a `void` pointer but maybe it is not a good idea. I ask this because I realized that I must attain to c++11 and template variables are introduced in c++14.

Comment: @MaPo Why can't you use the first example that works?  Could to you add to your question an example of the code you'd like to work, but doesn't?  I don't understand why you need the function pointer.