# How to pass function template as template parameter?

Tags: c++, templates

Here is an example :

```
template <typename T> void show()
{
    printf("%s\n", typeid(T).name());
}

template <> void show<int>()
{
    printf("int\n");
}

template <typename T> void go()
{
    show<T>();
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    go<int>();
    go<void>();
    return 0;
}
```

It works.

But in function go, show is hardcoded. I want it as a parameter. Something like that :

```
template <typename F, typename T> void go()
{
    F<T>();
}
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    go<show, int>();
    go<show, void>();
    return 0;
}
```

I failed. g++ told me :

> error: ‘F’ is not a template

And if I put show into a class, it's ok ：

```
struct cls
{
    template <typename T> static void show2()
    {
        printf("%s\n", typeid(T).name());
    }
};

template <> void cls::show2<int>()
{
    printf("int\n");
}

template <typename T, typename C> void go2()
{
    C::template show2<T>();
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    go2<int, cls>();
    go2<double, cls>();
    return 0;
}
```

In fact, I pass class name as template parameter, but not function name. So, function name show2 is still hardcode in go2.

Can I pass function name(show / show2) as template parameter?
Impossible? and why?
Or I just need to fix some mistakes?

Comment: The problem is that `show` is not a function name, it is a name of template function. The workaround is to replace it with a wrapper template class with a static method and pass name of this template class as template template parameter.

Comment: You can/should pass a pointer to the function.

Comment: @user12002570 OP can/should not do it because `show` is not a function.

Comment: Why not `template<class Func> void go(Func f) {f();}`  which can be called as `go(show<int>)`?    At the call site this explicitly passes a specialisation of the template `show` (with template parameter `int`) and calls it.

Comment: Bascially same as [Template function as a template argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697180/template-function-as-a-template-argument). In particular, [you have to use a template template parameter. Unfortunately, you cannot pass template template function as a type, because it has to be instantiated first. But there is a workaround with dummy structures](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4697356/12002570)

Comment: @user12002570 That link is not fundamentally different from the last snippet in the question.

Comment: add a level of indirection such that `go` always calls (templated) `operator()` of some type. A lambda can be used to wrap any function or call to static method: https://godbolt.org/z/xc4Ph7Whx

Comment: Wrap function in functor [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/4h6c355jf).

Answer (score -1):

A function template is not a valid template paramter. The valid things are class templates, types, and values of some [*structural type*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters).

You can instantiate the function template to get a function, which is a valid template parameter.

```
template <auto F> void go()
{
    F();
}
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    go<show<int>>();
    go<show<void>>();
    return 0;
}
```

[See it on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/jh7eMsGaf)

If you need to keep the type `T` separate, then your class with a member function of a specified name is the best way. I would suggest using `operator()`.

Comment: This does not address initial problem of supplying parameters of function template inside of `go`. What if it needs to be changed to `show<typename T::value_type>();` or something.